# VSCode Java extension isn't running

Tags: java, macos, javafx, vscode-extensions

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBmhL.png)

Java extension for vscode just analyzes for something infinitely, so I can't run my project. Before it worked properly and I didn't change anything

I did the following:

- cleaned java lsp (language server) and shared indexes
- switched to release extension version from pre release
- reloaded window, IDE and OS after actions above

Comment: It is better to use Eclipse

Comment: It Is even better to use the free Community Edition of IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

**Preface**

If you want to develop with Java, use IntelliJ IDEA for this.

You will never get happy with VSC for Java.

**Solution**

Step 1:
Download the free version of IntelliJ IDEA.

Direct Link for Windows:
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/download-thanks.html?platform=windows&code=IIC

Direct Link for Linux:
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/download-thanks.html?platform=linux&code=IIC

Other versions such MacOS:
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/?section=windows

Step 2: Install and get happy

Everything will work out of the box and will be preconfigured perfectly fine for you.